# How to send crawler4j data to CrawlerManager?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, crawler4j

I'm working with a project where user can search some websites and look for pictures which have unique identifier.

```
public class ImageCrawler extends WebCrawler {

private static final Pattern filters = Pattern.compile(
        ".*(\\.(css|js|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf" +
                "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

private static final Pattern imgPatterns = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?))$");

public ImageCrawler() {
}

@Override
public boolean shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url) {
    String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
    if (filters.matcher(href).matches()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (imgPatterns.matcher(href).matches()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void visit(Page page) {
    String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();

    byte[] imageBytes = page.getContentData();
    String imageBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
    try {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(urlScan.getOwner(), null));
        DecodePictureResponse decodePictureResponse = decodePictureService.decodePicture(imageBase64);
        URLScanResult urlScanResult = new URLScanResult();
        urlScanResult.setPicture(pictureRepository.findByUuid(decodePictureResponse.getPictureDTO().getUuid()).get());
        urlScanResult.setIntegrity(decodePictureResponse.isIntegrity());
        urlScanResult.setPictureUrl(url);
        urlScanResult.setUrlScan(urlScan);
        urlScan.getResults().add(urlScanResult);
        urlScanRepository.save(urlScan);
    }

    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        //Picture is not in our database
    }
}
```

Crawlers will be run independently. ImageCrawlerManager class, which is singletone, run crawlers.

```
public class ImageCrawlerManager {

private static ImageCrawlerManager instance = null;


private ImageCrawlerManager(){
}

public synchronized static ImageCrawlerManager getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new ImageCrawlerManager();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
public void startCrawler(URLScan urlScan, DecodePictureService decodePictureService, URLScanRepository urlScanRepository, PictureRepository pictureRepository){

    try {
        CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
        config.setCrawlStorageFolder("/tmp");
        config.setIncludeBinaryContentInCrawling(true);

        PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
        RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
        RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);

        CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);
        controller.addSeed(urlScan.getUrl());

        controller.start(ImageCrawler.class, 1);
        urlScan.setStatus(URLScanStatus.FINISHED);
        urlScanRepository.save(urlScan);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        urlScan.setStatus(URLScanStatus.FAILED);
        urlScan.setFailedReason(e.getMessage());
        urlScanRepository.save(urlScan);
    }
}
```

How to send every image data to manager which decode this image, get the initiator of search and save results to database? In code above I can run multiple crawlers and save it to database. But unfortunately when i run two crawlers simultaneously, I can store two search results but all of them are connected to the crawler which was run first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **inject** your database service into your `ẀebCrawler` instances and not use a singleton to manage the result of your web-crawl.

`crawler4j` supports a custom `CrawlController.WebCrawlerFactory` (see [here](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) for reference), which can be used with Spring to inject your database service into a `ImageCrawler` instance.

Every single crawler thread should be responsible for the whole process you described with (e.g. by using some specific services for it):

> decode this image, get the initiator of search and save results to
>   database

Setting it up like this, your database will be the **only source of truth** and you will not have to deal with synchronizing crawler-states between different instances or user-sessions.